# Azure Blob Storage BlockBob - Replaced File Not Shown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, caching, azure-storage

I am using Azure blob storage in my project.And when I am trying to update an existing file, if the new file name is different from the current file name it will be updated and shown through the url. But the case is if the new file has a different name from the current file name, yes it will be updated but it will not be shown through the url. When I meant through the URL it means through the browser. And it is not being cached by the browser. I tried clearing browser cached and even used a different browser.

The URL is - https://cubictechdemo.blob.core.windows.net/media/Cache%202017_12062017111606.pdf

But still if I passed a query like https://cubictechdemo.blob.core.windows.net/media/Cache%202017_12062017111606.pdf?xxx

it will give me the updated file.
And however it would be downloaded through blockBlob.DownloadToStream() method. The url shows the old file and the downloadToStream gives me the updated file.

I don't know why this is happening. I am using UploadFromStream method. I can only get the new file if i passed some query.

```
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName); 
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileInput);
    blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
```

Does anybody know why that is? Thank You.

Comment: Are you expecting the URL to change, even though the new blob has the same name as the old?